# Primality test with polynomial congruence (preliminary to AKS algorithm)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I have trouble in understanding the proof of this primality criterion:

$n$ is prime if and only if the congruence $(x+b)^n \equiv x^n+b \,\,\,\text{mod} \,n$ holds for every $b\in \mathbb{Z}$.

In particular my problem is to understand the proof of the implication $(x+b)^n \equiv x^n+b \,\,\, \text{mod} \,n$ holds for every $b\in \mathbb{Z} \implies n $ is prime.

One assumes by contradiction $n$ composite, takes a prime factor $p$ of $n$, and then shows that $p^\alpha$, which is by definition the highest power of $p$ which divides $n$, does not divide the binomial coefficient $n\choose p$, and so a fortiori $n$ cannot divide $n\choose p$. But why this conclusion leads to the negation of the congruence? And I have also another question: how do I have to interpret a polynomial congruence with a "free" indeterminate $x$ like that? Is it simply a numerical congruence which holds for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ or does it have to be regarded in a different way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $x$ is an indeterminate. The congruence means all coefficients of the polynomial on the left are congruent to the corresponding coefficient on the right. So if $n$ is not prime, the coefficient of $x^p$ is nonzero on the left (for suitable values of $b$), but zero on the right.

Comment: Ok, so it is viewed as a congruence term by term, thanks. So the thesis follows from the fact that $n$ does not divide $n\choose p$ by considering $b=1$ for example, in which case that binomial coefficient is exactly the coefficient of the term $x^p$. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Any $b$ that is not divisible by $p$ would leave the coefficient of $x^p$ not divisible by $n$.

Comment: Ok, now it's all clear, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Let's begin with

> And I have also another question: how do I have to interpret a polynomial congruence with a "free" indeterminate $x$ like that?

That is to be interpreted as congruence of all corresponding coefficients, or equivalently as equality in the polynomial ring $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[x]$.

And from that immediately follows the first point, the coefficient of $x^p$ in $(x+b)^n$ is $\binom{n}{p}b^{n-p}$, and if $b$ is not divisible by $p$, the coefficient is not divisible by $p^\alpha$, hence not by $n$, so then $(x+b)^n \not\equiv x^n+b^n \pmod{n}$.

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out why $p^{\alpha}$ doesn't divide $\binom{n}{p}$.